# Multiple nested routes broke at 4th

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Im nesting some routes with vue-router but at 4th nested route, it brokes all content except the main content

mainComponent->(router-view)->sub1->(router-view)->sub2->(router-view)->finalComponent

```
import childs1 from '@/router/modules/childs1'
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/main',
      name: 'main',
      component: mainComponent,
      children: chids1
    }
  ]

//childs1.js
import childs2 from '@/router/modules/childs2'
export default [
  {
    path: 'sub1',
    name: 'sub1',
    component: sub1,
    children: chids2
  }
]

//childs2.js
import childs3 from '@/router/modules/childs3'
export default [
  {
    path: 'sub2',
    name: 'sub2',
    component: sub2,
    children: chids3
  }
]

//childs3.js
export default [
  {
    path: 'final',
    name: 'final',
    component: finalComponent
  }
```

I have this results

### /main

---

main init

-

main end

---

### /main/sub1

---

main init

sub1 init

-

sub1 end

main end

---

### /main/sub1/sub2

---

main init

sub1 init

sub2 init

-

sub2 end

sub1 end

main end

---

### /main/sub1/sub2/final

---

main init

-

main end

---

where it should be

### /main/sub1/sub2/final

---

main init

sub1 init

sub2 init

final init

-

final end

sub2 end

sub1 end

main end

---

Comment: it works on fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/cnq3r6p4/) but not with multiple files

Comment: my bad i was validating the final route with beforeEnter and missed the next()